Intellij error - Abnormal build process termination
I'm developing some very simple algorithms to learn java. Suddenly IntelliJ started giving me this problem when I try to run a program (which is without errors or warnings). The strange thing is that it doesn't always happen: sometimes it runs the program, other times it gives this error.
Here's the screenshot.
IntelliJ Build Output
Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/jna/amd64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/Utente/IdeaProjects/my-java-core -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-3313549392546378649 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=it -Duser.country=IT -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2024.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=21.0.4 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/compile-server/my-java-core_73adcd33/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder.fs.case.sensitive=false "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-7869070725842733155-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/platform-loader.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/trove.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jetbrains.kotlinx.metadata.jvm.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps/java-compiler-charts-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/javaee-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/JPA/lib/jps/javaee-jpa-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49153 61a4f435-ebd9-4763-bc2c-af2a13f4dabc C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/compile-server
Be careful, logger will be shut down earlier than application: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7b23ec81
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:49153; reason: Address already in use: getsockopt: /127.0.0.1:49153
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address already in use: getsockopt: /127.0.0.1:49153
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: getsockopt
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:689)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Exiting.

This is what I tried in order to solve the problem:

execute the "automatically" button proposed by IntelliJ, so that it's not blocked by Windows Defender
execute Maven's clean operation
recreate the project from scratch with and without Maven
update to the last version IntelliJ (2024.2.3) and java (23) on my pc

The part that makes me most doubtful is this:
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:49153; reason: Address already in use: getsockopt: /127.0.0.1:49153
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address already in use: getsockopt: /127.0.0.1:49153
I really ran out of ideas.

This is some networking issue. Try netsh winsock reset from the Administrator console and reboot. Use TcpView to see what process uses the port number from the error message. Is it some real process? Is it a Java process? In case it's a stuck Java process, get jstack thread dump of it and share it somewhere.

@CrazyCoder thanks, I tried running a few programs and now everything works! It was enough to execute netsh winsock reset and restart the pc.
